# make a search in recylerview

Tags: firebase, android-studio

I want to make a search on recyclerview, but the data appears if the phone is turned off and then turned on again, why is that?

the example photo

[the app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5jxfJ.jpg)

[When i'm search the recylerview is blank](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W1ogj.jpg)

[but when the phones turned off and then turn on again, the data is appear](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GcSfH.jpg)

here's the code in fragment class

```
 //search
editText = view.findViewById(R.id.searchServant);
    searchButton = view.findViewById(R.id.button2);

    searchButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String s = editText.getText().toString();
            firebaseSearch(s);
        }
    });


    //RecylerviewDatabaseServant
    recyclerViewdatabase = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewServant);
    mManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
    recyclerViewdatabase.setLayoutManager(mManager);

    FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Servant> options =
            new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Servant>().setQuery(FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Servant")
                    , Servant.class)
                    .build();
   servantAdapter = new ServantAdapter(options);
    recyclerViewdatabase.setAdapter(servantAdapter);
    //End
```

> here the function firebase search

```
private void firebaseSearch(String s) {


        FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Servant> options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Servant>().setQuery(FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
                .getReference().child("Servant").orderByChild("name").startAt(s).endAt(s + "\uf8ff"), Servant.class).build();


        servantAdapter = new ServantAdapter(options);
        recyclerViewdatabase.setAdapter(servantAdapter);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try add this line in You search query

```
private void firebaseSearch(String s) {


    FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Servant> options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Servant>().setQuery(FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
            .getReference().child("Servant").orderByChild("name").startAt(s).endAt(s + "\uf8ff"), Servant.class).build();


    servantAdapter = new ServantAdapter(options);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager({**context**}));
    recyclerViewdatabase.setAdapter(servantAdapter);
    servantAdapter.startListening();
}
```